# Identify this button/rivet

Tags: uniform, naval

[Naval button?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEFTo.jpg)

I found this at an former telegraph, pony express and stage stop in NV. It looks like a rivet used mostly for leather or pouches from my research but I really can't  ID it for sure 
[image: button/rivet]

Comment: What are the measurements?

Comment: I would be careful announcing locations where you 'find' things.[Nevada](http://www.mdhtalk.org/cf/city-regulation.cfm?st=NV) is mostly BLM and they frown on any 'artifact' removal.

Comment: It seems naval, but the rope starts top left and down instead of top right and down, plus there's no eagle, so it's rather unlike the symbols used by the US navy. [This has a similar pattern](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/Antique-Navy-23mm-Fouled-Anchor-Uniform-Button-SCOVILL-MFG-CO-Backmark-/391807743461?hash=item5b398fb5e5) though, in case it helps you narrow your research.

Comment: It may be useful to search for images of "fouled anchor".  (you may wish to search "fouled anchor -globe -eagle" to exclude images from the goat locker.

Comment: It does look somewhat  like a Royal Navy fouled anchor, for instance as seen in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Navy_ratings_rank_insignia , especially on the OR-4 and OR-7 rank badges.

Comment: Simikar to some of the images here: http://www.militaryheritage.com/button3.htm. About halfway down royal navy seaman

Comment: I  think I  may be way off. I was shown  the trademarks for North & Judd spur  makers and it looks like a strap latch from a spur which makes way more sense.